# Obtener valor de un input tipo date en formato personalizado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Con este código obtengo la fecha seleccionada:

```js
let fechaDevolucion = $("#fechaDevolucion").val();
console.log(fechaDevolucion);
```

```html
<div class="input-group input-group-static my-3">
    <label>Fecha De Devolucion</label>
    <input name="fechaDevolucion" id="fechaDevolucion" required min="" type="date" class="form-control" value="2017-03-10">
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-u7e5khyithlIdTpu22PHhENmPcRdFiHRjhAuHcs05RI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero quiero darle este formato a la fecha:

> March 10, 2017

Pero lo obtengo en este formato:

> 2017-03-10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes dos formas de obtener los textos que deseas:

- [`Date.toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)
- [`Intl.DateTimeFormat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)

Aquí tienes un ejemplo de uso, en el que obtengo cada elemento por separado para montar la cadena a tu gusto:

```js
const fecha = new Date(fechaDevolucion.value);
const lenguaje = "en-GB";
const opciones = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
};

const texto1 = fecha.toLocaleDateString(lenguaje, opciones);
const texto2 = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(lenguaje, opciones).format(fecha);

/* Se obtiene la misma salida */
console.log(texto1, texto2);

// Para conseguir: "March 10, 2017"
const año = fecha.toLocaleDateString(lenguaje, { year: "numeric" });
const mes = fecha.toLocaleDateString(lenguaje, { month: "long" });
const día = fecha.toLocaleDateString(lenguaje, { day: "numeric" });

const fechaDevolucionPropia = `${mes} ${día}, ${año}`;
console.log(fechaDevolucionPropia);
```

```html
<div class="input-group input-group-static my-3">
    <label>Fecha De Devolucion</label>
    <input name="fechaDevolucion" id="fechaDevolucion"
      value="2017-03-10"
      required min="" type="date" class="form-control"
    />
</div>
```